# DLookup In Access 2010 using IsNull and multiple criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, isnull, filtered-lookup

Essentially I am trying to find if a user is currently logged in before making a new row with TimeIn, but with the code as it is written, a user can check in multiple times without checking out (TLog_TImeOut field is null).  My code is listed below.

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[TLog_TimeIn]", "TIMELOG", "IsNull(TLog_TImeOut)= True And NetID =  '[TempVars]![CurrentID]'")) Then
MsgBox ("Please Check out!")
DoCmd.Close acForm, "CHECKIN", acSaveNo
Exit Sub
Else
   NetID = [TempVars]![CurrentID]
   TLog_TimeIn = Now()
   MsgBox ("Thanks for checking in!")
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "CHECKIN", acSaveYes
Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DLOOKUP` should be more like this:

```
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[TLog_TimeIn]", "TIMELOG", "TLog_TimeOut Is Null And NetID = '" & Forms![TempVars]![CurrentID] & "'")) Then
```

Specifically your condition -

```
IsNull(TLog_TImeOut)= True And NetID =  '[TempVars]![CurrentID]'
```

Should be treated like the `WHERE` condition in a **SQL** statement.

First, if possible, you want to avoid Access functions for speed reasons (not a big deal in this particular case) so using `Is Null` is better than `IsNull(XXX)=True` but especially this part:

```
NetID =  '[TempVars]![CurrentID]'
```

This is going to literally compare NetID to the string '[TempVar]![CurrentID]' so what you want is to build this string like this:

```
NetID = '" & Forms![TempVars]![CurrentID] & "'"
```

(Assuming [TempVars] is a hidden form that you use to save variable values) which if CurrentID is BOB on that form will yield:

```
NetID = 'BOB'
```

Which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Dan!!!!!  However, TempVars is a function in access 2010 which allows you to pass variables from one form to the next...just got rid of the Forms! and it worked!!!

Comment: Great! You kids and your new-fangled [TempVars] -- why in my day we had to walk uphill in the snow to use a hidden form for the same purpose and we were glad to do it!